# GNU sort - What is the default algorithm used for comparison?

Tags: linux, sorting, gnu, gnu-sort

I need help understanding the default algorithm for GNU's sort. I assumed it did a lexicographic sort, however I found out some behavior that does not correspond to that, as an example take the following strings:

```
alex.
alex.a
alex.Z
alexa
alex0
alexZ
alex.~
alex
alex.|
alex.}
alex.abc
```

And sort them on a shell using sort like `echo 'stuff' | sort`

This is the result I get:

```
alex
alex.
alex.~
alex.|
alex.}
alex0
alexa
alex.a
alex.abc
alexZ
alex.Z
```

And I can't figure out why `alex0` and `alexa` appear in between `alex.}` and `alex.a`

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: btw, let's see if someone guesses my name hehe

Comment: +1 for added incentive :)

Comment: btw, did you see the output using `-d` flag?

Comment: yeah, same thing happens

Comment: @almosnow Terminology thing, but I think it's a lot clearer (and more correct) to talk about the `total order` or `linear order` on characters used by `sort`. It's true that a linear order is usually implemented via some algorithm that outputs `< 0, 0, > 0` but that's sort of an implementation detail...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorting by and large depends on LOCALE settings:

```
$ sort sort 
alex
alex.
alex.~
alex.|
alex.}
alex0
alexa
alex.a
alex.abc
alexZ
alex.Z
$ LC_ALL=C sort sort
alex
alex.
alex.Z
alex.a
alex.abc
alex.|
alex.}
alex.~
alex0
alexZ
alexa
```

Comment: That solves my specific need, however it would still be interesting to find out what the default comparison function it uses.

Comment: @almosnow: It *is* lexicographic, as you correctly assumed in the question.However how **lexicographic** gets interpreted depends on your locale.

Comment: Yeah, but still it's really weird to not see all 'alex.*' entries grouped together, I wonder how would that function look like. I guess I'll dive into the source code when I have some spare time.

Comment: @almosnow: I don't think looking at the source will shed much light.  Look at the UTF codepoints of your locale; chances are that the . is irrelevant (ignored altogether) for the sorting.

Answer (score 4):

GNU Sort implements mergesort. You can find the complete answer posted in super user thread. https://superuser.com/questions/234054/unix-sort-algorithm-implementation

Comment: ok, my mistake, I should have asked for the default 'comparison' algorithm. thanks!

Comment: This question concerns the *ordering* used by `sort(1)`, e.g., "why `alex0` and `alexa` appear in between `alex.}` and `alex.a`", which is an observable property, not the *sorting algorithm*, which is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

Try "sort InFile.txt" on this file then change the first word Start to Begin & explain the difference? I keep setting LC_LOCAL-C to no effect.
InFile.txt

```
Start report    /* Change Start to Begin to see difference */    
MISSING..
NEW file.
Updated files
/home/me/path/To/file.txt
/home/me/path/To/new.txt
/home/me/path/To/old.txt
/home/me/path/To/lost.txt
/home/me/path/To/file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think I've figured this out.  The "/" character seems to be ignored.  I wonder where that detail is documented, maybe it is hidden in LC_ALL.